# How to parse an array of objects to a list of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list

In my Vue application I have a list of objects looking like this:

```js
const arr = [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: 'Max',
     grade: 3
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: 'Lisa',
     grade: 2
   }
];
```

Now I want every object in this array to be a single string for itself. I know there is `JSON.stringifty` but this makes my whole array to a string and not every single object.

So the result should be something like:

```js
const arr = [
"{id:1,name:'Max',grade:3}",
"{id:2,name:'Max',grade:3}"
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be

```
const myJsonArr = arr.map((v) => JSON.stringify(v))
```

Comment: `JSON` is a module, not an object, hence `arr.map(JSON.stringify)` would be fine

Comment: @gog I wouldn't do that. map passes an integer index and the original array as the 2nd and 3rd arguments. stringify expects different things

Comment: `If replacer is anything other than a function or an array... all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.  If space is anything other than a string or number... no white space is used.` - so we're fine.

Comment: @gog Having to delve deep into the docs about exactly what parameters `map` uses to invoke its callback vs the parameters accepted by `JSON.stringify` just isn't worth the time. By wrapping, we can be very sure, at first glance, that `JSON.stringify` is being called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
let array = arr.map(item=>JSON.stringify(item))
```

Comment: You need to pass `item` to stringify